# Why does Stata report zero observations when the variable has non-missing values?

Tags: string, stata

I have a variable called `co_dormant` that takes on two string values:
`Y` or `N`.

So far, when I type `summarize co_dormant`, I get zero observations.
However, when I type `table co_dormant`, I get the frequency of `Y` and `N`.

I want to keep all observations that have non-missing co_dormant, and when I type

```
keep if co_dormant != .
```

all the observations are dropped.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

`summarize` is meant for numeric type variables. (What would be, for example, the mean of a string variable?)

`table` by default gives the *frequency*. Stata can count frequencies for either string or numeric type variables.

If you want to drop missings (what Stata considers missings) you can use the `missing()` function. This works for both string and numeric variables:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str1 myvar
Y
N
""
end

list

drop if missing(myvar)

list
```

See `help missing` for details on missing values.

If you executed what you say you executed, and the variable was string type, you would get an error:

```
. input ///
> str1 myvar

         myvar
  1. Y
  2. N
  3. ""
  4. end

. 
. list

     +-------+
     | myvar |
     |-------|
  1. |     Y |
  2. |     N |
  3. |       |
     +-------+

. 
. keep if myvar != .
type mismatch
r(109);
```